# Dynamic Array Implementation in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, realloc

- Does realloc function in C allocate contiguous memory space?
- I am trying to implement dynamic integer array. Should I increment pointer by size of array element or by 1?
- Are there any other better ways to implement dynamic array in C?

Comment: Do you mean "contiguous with the original memory"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does realloc function in C allocate contiguous memory space?

Yes.

> I am trying to implement dynamic integer array. Should I increment pointer by size of array element or by 1?

You should increase your pointer by `1`.

> Are there any other better ways to implement dynamic array in C?

Using `malloc` family functions is the only way. But in C99 and latter you can use [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (but it has some limitations as it allocates memory on stack).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I need to change my code now!

Comment: @user3224177; What change?

Comment: Doesn't make sense to increment size by size of a pointer, it should double the memory or, better, increase it by 150%. It gives the amortized constant time for append! And, yes, the best way in C is using realloc.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, just like `malloc()` does.
2. If you have an `int* ptr` which is a pointer to an element of a dynamically allocated `int` array, a simple `ptr++` will point to the next element.
3. Using `malloc()` and `realloc()` in C seems to me a good option for dynamic arrays.

Comment: My comment above also applies here.